# Return an else statement for foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, logic

I've spent about two hours trying to figure this out so finally I'm going to post it here.

I have a listing of jobs in a JSON feed that I'm pulling into PHP. I want to get all the jobs for a specific location. The location logic works fine, and I'm getting all the proper jobs.

My problem comes with getting an `else` statement to work. If I use the code below, it will return `'No jobs available'` for each instance of a job. I can use `i++` to only return it once, but it will return no matter what - whether my jobs match or not.

```
// This code does not work properly

foreach ( $json['jobs'] as $job ) {

$location = $job['job']['location'];

    if ( $location === $current_location ) {
        echo 'Job title';
    } else {
        echo 'No jobs available';
    }
}
```

This will return something like:

```
Job title
Job title
No jobs available
Job title
```

So basically I need to somehow get that `else` statement out of the foreach loop, and only display once.

I'm looking for, in English: for each job, list the jobs for the current location. If the current location has no jobs available, print a statement saying "No jobs available for your location."

I apologize for such a novice logic related question. Couldn't find the correct answer after a bit of searching.

Comment: in else set a `flag` to true if job is not available and if flag is true output no job is available.

Comment: Might be easier to rebuild the array into a location => jobs type of setup. Then using $current_location, you could just do an index check on the new array and if it exists, pull, all child elements/jobs found under it.

Comment: Is the code you've shown in the question just the code for printing the jobs for one location?

Comment: Yes, I only want to print jobs for one location. The jobs are printing fine, my only issue is getting the "No jobs available" to print when no jobs are available for that specific location. It is either always true or always false with my logic.

Comment: So, does each `$job` contain multiple jobs?

Comment: For example, in `foreach ( $json['jobs'] as $job ) {` if I do `echo $job['job']['title'];` it will return the job title for every available job. So yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a variable to put this information:

```
$jobs = [];

foreach ( $json['jobs'] as $job ) {

    $location = $job['job']['location'];

    if ( $location === $current_location ) {
        $jobs[] = $job['job']['title'];
    }
}
if(count($jobs) === 0) {
    echo '"No Jobs Found" found';
} else {
    foreach($jobs as $job) {
        echo "See this awesome job: ".$job;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your comment. I did that, however, "No Jobs Found" prints out on both pages. This is because my `if` statement is looking for jobs from a specific location, and the `else` lists all available jobs. Therefore, `if ($noJobs)` returns true in both instances. :-/

Comment: Now I understood your problem. Edited, take a look

Comment: This only works if the jobs array contains just 1 location. Cycling through all the jobs, your code will always mark $noJobs to true if there is more than 1 location.

This was a comment before you made your edit. The updated code should work

Comment: I'm not getting it to work at the moment but I'll keep trying. In my array, the job title is `$job['job']['title']`.This keeps returning 500 although I can't find any syntax errors...

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much, and sorry for the delay on accepting. There's an extra bracket after the foreach, and when I listed the `$jobs = [];` at the top it didn't work, but after removing those two things, I simply made $jobs[] = $job['job'] and removed the first multi-array from my variables in the else.

Comment: Good improvements. Edited to removed that extra bracket.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is tell whether or not a single location is represented inside of your `$jobs` array, you don't need your own explicit loop to search it.  You can combine [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) with [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get either an index of a job at the location or a boolean `false`:

```
$location = 'some location';
$key = array_search($location, array_column($json['jobs'], 'location'));

if(false === $key) {
    // Array has no jobs at $location
} else {
    // Array has jobs at $location
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but couldn't get it to work. I think what you have as `$location` is what I have as `$current_location`, and `$jobs` is `$job`, but not working as of yet.

Comment: Note that this is not within a loop at all, you should be passing it the entire array containing all of the jobs. In your question above, you're looping over `$json['jobs']`, so I would try that

Answer (score 0):

Use array_filter() to filter out job items with matched locations using a simple custom function instead of a foreach loop.

Then just check if that filtered array is empty. If it is then echo "no jobs" message; if it is not empty then loop with foreach job item for that matched location.

```
<?php

function is_current_location($job) {
    if ( $job ['location'] == CURRENT_LOCATION ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$jobs = array_filter( $json['jobs'], "is_current_location" );

if ( empty ( $jobs ) ) {
    echo 'No jobs available';
} else {
    foreach ( $jobs as $job ) {
        echo $job['job_title'];
    }
}
```